# Debugging the return value of a jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, debugging

I am looking for a way to debug what a jquery selector returns. I have tried using `toString()`, but that only ever returns `[object Object]`.

What I am actually trying to do is to attach a callback to radio buttons. And `onclick`
on one of the buttons, I want to submit the enclosing form.

Therefore I try to do something like this:

```
$(".rating").stars({
    cancelShow: false,
    callback: function(ui, type, value, event) {
        $(this).closest('form').ajaxSubmit();
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, nothing happens.

Here is a complete example of what I am trying to do:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8000/media/js/jquery.js?v=1.4.2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8000/media/js/jquery.form.js?v=2.4.3"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8000/media/js/jquery-ui.custom.min.js?v=1.8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://localhost:8000/media/js/jquery.ui.stars.js?v=3.0.0b38"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://localhost:8000/media/css/jquery.ui.stars.css?v=3.0.0b38" />        

<body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".rating").children().not(":radio").hide();
        $(".rating").stars({
            cancelShow: false,
            callback: function(ui, type, value, event) {
                alert('NodeName: ' + this.nodeName);
                $(this).each(function() {
                    alert($(this).html());
                });

                alert($(this).length);
            }
        });
    });
 </script>

 <ul class="list">
  <li>
   <form class="rating" id="rating-1" action="/sniphunter/rate/1/" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="score" value="1" id="rating-1-1" />
    <input type="radio" name="score" value="2" id="rating-1-2" />
    <input type="radio" name="score" value="3" id="rating-1-3" />
    <input type="radio" name="score" value="4" id="rating-1-4" />
    <input type="radio" name="score" value="5" id="rating-1-5" />
    <input type="submit" value="Rate"/>
   </form>
  </li>
 </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded the [Star Rating Widget](http://orkans-tmp.22web.net/star_rating/) (it looks like the same one you are using) and did some digging... the stars plugin completely removes the radio buttons and replaces them with div's and links. When you select a star, it saves the value in a hidden input inside the form.

So, after messing around with it, I found that you can get to the form using `ui.$form`, so try this:

```
$(function(){
    $(".rating").children().not(":radio").hide();
    $(".rating").stars({
        cancelShow: false,
        callback: function(ui, type, value, event)
        {
            alert( ui.$form.attr('id') );  // alerts the form ID
            ui.$form.ajaxSubmit();
        }
    });
});
```

---

Edit: Oh and if you want to access your original radio buttons, they are saved into the ui object as well inside of `ui.$rboxs`. The following snippet will alert the ID of the original radio button:

```
$(function(){
    $(".rating").children().not(":radio").hide();
    $(".rating").stars({
        cancelShow: false,
        callback: function(ui, type, value, event)
        {
            alert( ui.$rboxs[(value-1)].id );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a million, that worked like a charm. Any hints how I could debug this myself the next time? I tried to use firebug, but still had no clue where I was in the DOM and what my selector was selecting etc...

Anyways many thanks for the help!

Comment: Actually I used firebug to figure it out. Instead of `alert( ui )` use `console.debug( ui )`. It will display the object (clickable and opens into a tree view) in the console that you can navigate through.

Comment: Thanks for the tip with the console, I always got "not defined" and didn't try further. The solution was to open the console Tab and now it works and I see the tree view and the form element :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) to see if they found anything (the most common case), like this:

```
$(".rating").stars({
  cancelShow: false,
  callback: function(ui, type, value, event) {
    alert($(this).closest('form').length);
    $(this).closest('form').ajaxSubmit();
  }
});
```

There are other options, for example if you wanted to iterate each one and spit out it's html so you know what it found you can use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) and [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/):

```
$(".rating").stars({
  cancelShow: false,
  callback: function(ui, type, value, event) {
    $(this).closest('form').each(function() {
      alert($(this).html());
    });
    $(this).closest('form').ajaxSubmit();
  }
});
```

These are two quick examples out of dozens, but usually `.length` shows the issue, e.g. `this` not being what you want it to be in that callback.

Comment: Thanks this already help that $(this) has length 1 and all my tries of different slectors has length 0.

Comment: @Fabian - Try `alert(this.nodeName);` see if it's even the element type you're after?

Comment: ohh well nodename is undefinded, so I really need a way to debug this properly :-(

Comment: @Fabian: Share some HTML and it might help us troubleshoot your problem better

Comment: @Fabian - `$(ui).closest('form').ajaxSubmit();` may be what you're after.

Comment: Just to let  you know, I edited my original question with a complete html example.

Answer (score 0):

### Debug / Show jQuery Selection with jQuery.alert()

I'm learning jQuery and this is the tool I made to help me debug my selections.  You can chain it in with your code and see what the selection is at that point.

**.alert() => LISTS THE FIRST HTML TAG OF EACH ELEMENT IN THE SELECTION.**

See the example below. Notice **.alert()** after the .find(): => [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StormDog/6uq8d9cg/)

```
$(".item-b").find("li").alert("MY MESSAGE").css("color", "red");
```

The alert box might look like this:
(can't post image until I get 10 points)

[imagine an alert box listing some elements]

Here is the tool:

```
(function ($) {
    // Lists out each element's first tag in alert box, chainable
    $.fn.alert = function (message) {
        if (typeof message === 'undefined') message = "";
        this.each(function () {
            message += "\n" + this.outerHTML.match(/<[a-z]+\b(?:[^'">]*|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*>/)[0];
        });
        console.log(message);
        alert(message);
        return this;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

I'm new at this, so any constructive comments are welcome ...